# How to view the changes of an imported file in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have a .js file that stores several json objects that will be used to dynamically create components in various parts of the app. For ex:

```
import langUtil from '../utilities/langUtil';
export default {
 ...
    DEFAULT_DAY_TIME: {
        "times": [
            {
                "name":langUtil.day_morning,
                "value":"1"
            },
            {
                "name":langUtil.day_afternoon,
                "value":"2"
            },
            {
                "name":langUtil.day_evening,
                "value":"3"
            }
        ],
    ...
}
```

langUtil uses the 'react-native-localization' package to give translations in various languages. Therefore, if the language is currently set to be English, it will show the text as "Morning" and if its French, "Matin" and so on. This actually works with no issue if I use langUtil.day_morning inside a component:

```
<Text>{langUtil.day_morning}</Text> //will show the correct language when language is changed
```

Because my app has an option to change language, I would like it to update all the text to the new language, and as mentioned, this works for when langUtil is used inside a component.

However, if I do this in render:

```
render() {
    const { DEFAULT_DAY_TIME} = json_constants;
```

and json_constants is imported like this:

```
import json_constants from '../../assets/json_constants';
```

It will not update when the text upon language change. I assume its because its already been imported and the language has already been set. So it will not re-import the file. I'm wondering if there is a way to change the language for those objects, or do I need to rethink the whole setup?

By the way, here is a simplified example of how those objects are used:

```
{DEFAULT_DAY_TIME.map(item => {
        return (
                <View key={item.value} style={styles.label} >
                        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
        );
})}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some playing around I've came up with a solution that worked for me. It's kind of 'hacky' but for now it does the job. So first, I converted all of `LangUtil` component references to be strings.

```
export const DEFAULT_DAY_TIME = {
    "times": [
        {
            "name":"langUtil.default.day_morning",
            "value":"1"
        },
        {
            "name":"langUtil.default.day_afternoon",
            "value":"2"
        },
        {
            "name":"langUtil.default.day_evening",
            "value":"3"
        }
    ],
...
```

I had to add  `default` because I need to use `require()` instead of `import` to make this work, and the React-Native-Localization package has a default object which is the currently set language.

And finally, in the file that I need the constants:

```
let LangUtil = require('../utilities/langUtil') //you can do this above your class declaration
import {DEFAULT_DAY_TIME} from '../../assets/json_constants';
```

and where you want to use the constants and view the text in the correct language, use eval():

```
{DEFAULT_DAY_TIME.map(item => {
    return (
            <View key={item.value} style={styles.label} >
                    <Text>{eval(item.name)}</Text>
            </View>
    );
})}
```

This may not be the best solution but it does the trick for me. Maybe it will help out someone else.